# Can anybody help me with a database organization script in Microsoft Visual Basic for Excel?

Tags: database, excel, vba

I'm not much of a programmer. I have been assigned the task of reorganizing an xml file with 7,000 products with 60 attributes each. The file needs to be reorganized so that the 60 attributes are the header and the products and their attributes are listed underneath of them. I have a bit of code rigged up to do this, but it doesn't quite work (actually it appears to work, it just never 'finishes').

```
    Sub Autosort()
Dim x As Long
Dim CL As Range
With Sheets("sheet1")
    For Each CL In Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            Select Case CL.Value
                Case "description"
                .Range("C" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "origin-zip"
                .Range("D" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "name"
                .Range("E" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "download"
                .Range("F" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "yahoo-shopping-category"
                .Range("G" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "abstract"
                .Range("H" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "product-size"
                .Range("I" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "cross-sell"
                .Range("J" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "label"
                .Range("K" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "free-shipping"
                .Range("L" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "multi-box-weights"
                .Range("M" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "orderable"
                .Range("N" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "product-url"
                .Range("O" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "taxable"
                .Range("P" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "adwords_grouping"
                .Range("Q" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "availability"
                .Range("R" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "headline"
                .Range("S" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "markup"
                .Range("T" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "size"
                .Range("U" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "keywords"
                .Range("V" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "inset"
                .Range("W" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "code"
                .Range("X" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "multi-box-dimensions"
                .Range("Y" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "icon"
                .Range("Z" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "free-shipping-method"
                .Range("AA" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "dimensions"
                .Range("AB" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "caption"
                .Range("AC" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "gender"
                .Range("AD" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "hide-contents"
                .Range("AE" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "adwords_labels"
                .Range("AF" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "brand"
                .Range("AG" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "vwd-enable-multi-cart"
                .Range("AH" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "global-free-ship-exclusion"
                .Range("AI" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "age-group"
                .Range("AJ" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "number-of-boxes"
                .Range("AK" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "condition"
                .Range("AL" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "sale-price"
                .Range("AM" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "color"
                .Range("AN" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "multi-add"
                .Range("AO" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "exclude-states"
                .Range("AP" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "flat-ship-rates"
                .Range("AQ" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "inset-1"
                .Range("AR" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "ysw-alt-tag"
                .Range("AS" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "inset-2"
                .Range("AT" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "inset-3"
                .Range("AU" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "inset-4"
                .Range("AV" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "inset-5"
                .Range("AW" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "invalid-ship-methods"
                .Range("AX" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "map-price"
                .Range("AY" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "new-icon"
                .Range("AZ" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "ship-alone"
                .Range("BA" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "ypath"
                .Range("BB" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "sale-icon"
                .Range("BC" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "image"
                .Range("BD" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "ship-weight"
                .Range("BE" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "page-title"
                .Range("BF" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "gift-certificate"
                .Range("BG" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "flat-ship-rate"
                .Range("BH" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "exclude-countries"
                .Range("BI" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "google-based-property-type"
                .Range("BJ" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case "price"
                .Range("BK" & (.Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)).Value = CL.Offset(, 1).Value
                Case Else

            End Select
Bail:
    Next CL
.Columns.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

If you need a sample of the data, please let me know, I would be happy to email a segment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it never finishes"?  Have you tried putting a code break and stepping through it?  Sounds like maybe an infinite loop.  I'd put in a code break, and as each variable is processed check to see what VBA thinks the value of it is.  You can do this by either hovering your mouse over the variable, or typing "?VariableName" in the Immediate window (without the quotes, of course).

Comment: I think you may be right Johnny. I put a break in on the line after Case "description". The code does exactly what I want, except I have to run it one product at a time (7,000+ to go haha). Any ideas on how I could get it to quit when it gets to the end of my product list?

Comment: Put another code break at the end of that section, and hit the "Run" button (the little arrow icon underneath the "Debug" and "Run" menu options at the top of the VBA editor).  It will run through the code until it hits the next break, so you don't have to step through it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Make column headings in A1:D1 (Attribute, Value, ID, Unique). In C2, put this formula and fill down

```
=IF(A2="description",SUM(C1)+1,C1)
```

It assumes that 'description' is the first attribute for each item. This will give each item an identifier.  In D2 put this formula and fill down

```
=ROW()
```

This will give each line a unique number.  Now create a pivot table from the data.

```
Column Labels = Attribute
Row Labels = OD
Values = Sum of Unique
```

Below the pivot table, put this formula in B7005 (or whatever row is below your data)

```
=B4
```

and fill across to the extent of you pivot table.  In B7006, put this formula

```
=INDEX(OriginalSheet!$B$2:$B$50000,MATCH(B5,OriginalSheet!$D$2:$D$50000,FALSE),1)
```

and fill right and down for as much data as you need. Finally select the range that starts with B7005, copy and paste special values over the top of itself.

If you have to do this more than once or you just really want to use code, then I would use something like this

```
    Sub TransposeXml()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rNext As Range

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    'assumes data starts in row 2 and you have 61 attributes
    'and that attributes are in the same order
    For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 61
        Set rNext = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Resize(61, 1).Copy
        rNext.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, , , True
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I will definitely try using the pivot table method. I'm definitely not particularly attached to using code. Thank you for your help.